# Function template taking a container type and a compare type

Tags: c++, templates

Below is some code that I would like to:

- take a container
- take a type
- return a new container of the same type containing
  objects (ptrs) from the original container that don't match the
  type of the compare type

```
#include <typeinfo>

// Algorithm wrapper around find_if that takes an STL collection and returns
// the subset in that collection not matching the compare.  Rely on return-value
// optimization for the returned container.
//
template< template<class, class> class TContainer, class TObject> //, class TCompare>
TContainer FindItemsNotMatching(const TContainer& container) //, TObject object)
{
    TContainer found;
    auto itemIt = container.begin(), end = container.end();
    auto compare = [](const TObject& item) -> bool
    {
        return typeid(*item) != typeid(TCompare);
    };

    while (itemIt != end)
    {
        itemIt = std::find_if(itemIt,
                              allEntities.end(),
                              compare);
        if (itemIt != end)
        {
            found.push_back(*itemIt);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

The caller would look hopefully like this:

```
std::vector<MyType*> vectorFullOfPolymorphicTypes;

std::vector<MyType*> notMatching = FindItemsNotMatching<std::vector<MyType*>, TypeDerivedFromMyType> (vectorFullOfPolymorphicTypes);
```

Unfortunately, I'm limited to using only Visual Studio 2012 at the moment, so no variadic templates are possible.  Any help is appreciated.  Here are some errors that I haven't figured out.

```
UdfAlgorithm.cpp:9: error: C3205: argument list for template template parameter 'TContainer' is missing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of template template parameter, just use `typename TContainer`:

You might change order of template parameter to avoid to provide deducible types.

You might use regular functor to simulate generic lambda (and so avoid to provide extra type), or use `value_type` from container.

C++11 introduces [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
template <class TObject, typename TContainer>
TContainer FindItemsNotMatching(const TContainer& container)
{
    TContainer found;
    auto predicate = [](const typename TContainer::value_type& item) -> bool
    {
        return typeid(*item) != typeid(TObject);
    };
    std::copy_if(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(found), predicate);

    return found;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<MyType*> myypes;

std::vector<MyType*> notMatching = FindItemsNotMatching<SomeDerivedType>(myTypes);
```

Comment: copy_if is great

Comment: Can you confirm that 'found' uses return value optimization to avoid a copy?

Comment: NRVO is possible for `found` but not guaranteed, at worst, it is moved.